# how to write a method in order to change database directly in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I made a Product class in Django models like :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True)
    description = models.TextField()
    image_url = models.URLField(verify_exists=True, max_length=200, blank = True, null = True)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

And i want to add a sell() method inside this class. well i did like:

```
def sell(self):
    result = self.quantity - 1
    return result
```

I want to change the value in database when just execute P.sell().

when i run it in the shell like this

```
 >>p = Product(title = 'title', description = 'des', quantity = 10)
 >>p.save()
 >>p.sell()
9    # it shown 9, but the database not changed still 10
```

## but if i continue to do like this

```
>> p.quantity = p.sell()
>> p.save()
```

## it can change the quantity to 9

but how can i just change the value when i just type p.sell() ?
how could i edit it in models?

Answer (score 1):

Uh...

```
def sell(self, save=True):
  self.quantity -= 1
  if save:
    self.save()
```

Comment: I'm wondering... Why did you add the `if save:` instead of automatically saving?

Comment: @yuvi: In case further modifications to the model attributes are desired before a save is needed.